# Compiling Gekko with auto-py-to-exe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gekko

My app starts in remote="False" , m.options.SOLVER=3 mode and works fine in vscode.
I needed to convert to exe file. Auto-Py-To-Exe can generate an exe file from a Python program. I managed to generate the exe from my gekko script. But when running the program, the solver shows these errors:

```
Error: The system cannot find the specified path.
Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for more error details,
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfzmt2vvbgk_model0\\options.json'
```

At runtime m.open_folder() can open the gekko path in the temp folder, but these files can't seem to be created.

In case of remote="True" and server=localhost: I try to run apmonitor server on localhost and it's ok in browser, but in code like this m = GEKKO(remote=True, server="http://127.0 .0.1") does not find the server and shows this error:

```
Server not found or unreachable.
```

In Remote="True" mode and default server: it works fine in code and exe file.

How to solve the above errors?
The first mode, Remote="False" is important to me.

This is the temp folder that the resolver creates in temp:

[image: Temp folder]

UPDATE: In auto-py-to-exe and other extensions like py2exe and pyinstaller you just need to say "include Gekko data files". The auto-py-to-exe interface includes the `--hidden-import` and `--collect-data` options and must be set to `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files` and `gekko`.

- You need to install pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe

Screenshot: [image: auto-py-to-exe commands]

In pyinstaller: [Compiling Gekko with Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181211/compiling-gekko-with-pyinstaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deploy a Gekko application:

- [Gekko in a Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573895/gekko-in-a-docker-container/74574236#74574236)
- [Compiling Gekko with Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181211/compiling-gekko-with-pyinstaller)

`Auto-Py-To-Exe` has a way to include a run directory. Instead of letting Gekko choose a temporary folder, try setting the run directory in the Python program so that it can be specified with "Add Folder" in `Auto-Py-To-Exe`. The animation at `auto-py-to-exe` on PyPI demonstrates how to add a folder.

[image: Auto-Py-To-Exe]

You can change the run directory by setting `m._path` before the `m.solve()` command. There is a [Step by step guide on how to run Gekko optimization locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781278/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-run-gekko-optimization-locally) Here is a complete example where a `run` directory is created in the current path.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import os

# create local Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# get current working directory
p = os.getcwd()
# create run directory
try:
    os.mkdir('run')
except:
    pass # directory exists
# change from tmp to new directory
m._path = os.path.join(p,'run')

# solve gekko problem
x = m.Var(value=0)      # define new variable, initial value=0
y = m.Var(value=1)      # define new variable, initial value=1
m.Equations([x + 2*y==0, x**2+y**2==1]) # equations
m.solve(disp=False)     # solve
print([x.value[0],y.value[0]])

# open run directory
m.open_folder()
```

Comment: hello mr Hedengren. Thank you so much for answer to me, finally understand how to solve this problem, and in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181211/compiling-gekko-with-pyinstaller  which you write in abov , talk about to edit spec and set from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
and datas=[] argument to "datas=collect_data_files('gekko') ,
I found these in auto-py-to-exe and set them, finally works fine.
I update question and upload screenshot from auto-py-to-exe ui.